# How to align a box and a picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, xcoffins

I want to align these two things on my document but how can I make it, because if I add `\hfill`, it doesn't make what I want. How can I make it?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}
\NewEnviron{mymdframed}[1][]{
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }
    \savebox0{
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}
    }
    \begin{mdframed}[
        backgroundcolor=white, 
        shadow=false, 
        shadowsize=0pt,
        roundcorner=0pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mymdframed}
    
        \textbf{\underline{Propriété :}} (admise)
        \smallskip
        \\
        Soient $A_1$, $A_2$, \dots , $A_p$, $p$ ensembles finis deux à deux disjoints.
        \\
        \smallskip
         On a : $|A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_p| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \dots + |A_p|$
    
    \end{mymdframed}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{scope}
            
            \clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
            \path[name path=a] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
                            
            \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
                
            \foreach \i/\j in {-1.5/$A_1$,-0.75/$A_2$,0/$A_3$,0.8/$\dots$,1.6/$A_p$}
            {
                \draw[black] (\i,-1) to[out=45, in=315] (\i,1);
                \node[black] at (\i,0) {\j};
            }
                
                      
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Please, post a complete MWE with preamble and all, so taht everyone can copy/paste your code and help you out. Especially when you have custom environment, it's difficult to know how it should behave. Now to give you a hint, you should have a look to `minipage` which allows you to place those kind of things alongside.

Comment: You have not enough space to place the two objects on the same line anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you are willing to use the space for marginal notes.

(1) Put the content into boxes. (Using the package `xcoffin`).

(2) Join the boxes: join the right-side-center of the `mdframed` box with left-side-center of the `tikzpicture` box, and add some horizontal space.

(3) Typeset the result as it where a text object.

[image: a]

Using `\SetVerticalCoffin\mymdf{0.65\textwidth}{%`  will fit the assembly in the textarea.

[image: b]

This is the code for the first figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}
\NewEnviron{mymdframed}[1][]{
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
    }
    \savebox0{
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}
    }
    \begin{mdframed}[
        backgroundcolor=white, 
        shadow=false, 
        shadowsize=0pt,
        roundcorner=0pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}

\usepackage{showframe}  % show mrgin <<<<<<<
\renewcommand\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}

\usepackage{xcoffins}% added <<<<<<<<<<

\NewCoffin\mymdf % create
\NewCoffin\mytikz

\begin{document}

\SetVerticalCoffin\mymdf{0.70\textwidth}{%  Adjust the with of the frame
    \begin{mymdframed}      
        \textbf{\underline{Propriété :}} (admise)
        \smallskip
        \\
        Soient $A_1$, $A_2$, \dots , $A_p$, $p$ ensembles finis deux à deux  disjoints.
        \\
        \smallskip
        On a : $|A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_p| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \dots + |A_p|$       
    \end{mymdframed}
}

    \SetHorizontalCoffin\mytikz{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{scope}           
        \clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
        \path[name path=a] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];          
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];           
        \foreach \i/\j in {-1.5/$A_1$,-0.75/$A_2$,0/$A_3$,0.8/$\dots$,1.6/$A_p$}
        {\draw[black] (\i,-1) to[out=45, in=315] (\i,1);
            \node[black] at (\i,0) {\j};
        }               
    \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
used as a canon for our understanding.

\JoinCoffins\mymdf[r,vc]\mytikz[l,vc](20pt,0pt)  % join the right side center of \mymdf with left side center of \mytikz
                                                % and displace 20pt to the right
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\mymdf % typeset the assembly in the current insertion point

Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
posteriori. Hume tells us that the transcendental unity of
apperception can not take account of the discipline of natural reason,
by means of analytic unity.
    
\end{document}
```